# apache2 servertokens

Tags: apache-2.2

I'm running a small apache2 web server, and I'm trying to figure out how to make a customized message for the servertokens, so when somebody does a banner grab, it returns something like "No information for you!". Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

`ServerTokens Prod` is essentially that, since "Apache" isn't particularly revealing (and you might as well throw in a `ServerSignature Off` to hide info on error pages, if you haven't already).  Is it insufficient in some way?

Comment: Thats the way I have it set up now. But I just want to be able to poke fun at anyone who does a banner grab, since I know my friends are going to try.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that without editing source code. See the following blog post for an idea of how to do it

http://benajnim.com/index.php/security/creating-a-custom-serversignature-in-apache/

Answer (score 1):

I am no longer running apache, but when I was I used a module called [Mod_security](http://modsecurity.org/) for various things.  One thing it could do is allow you to set a custom ServerSignature as you are asking to do here.

I would hesitate to suggest you install a module to do just that one thing, but since you mention you want to prevent offsite image linking some of the other features mod_security has to offer might be attractive to you.

I can say that from experience mod_security is, in my opinion, a *must-have* for most public facing linux webservers running Apache.